# pass value as argument into handler

Tags: applescript

What is the proper way to pass `list view` as an argument into the function?  If I set view_type inside the function it works, but if I set it outside the function, it does not.

```
#works
the_function()
on the_function()
    tell application "finder"
        set view_type to list view
        set current view of window 1 to view_type
    end tell
end the_function

#fails
set view_type to list view
the_function(view_type)
on the_function(view_type)
    tell application "finder"
        set current view of window 1 to view_type
    end tell
end the_function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only the Finder knows what a "list view" is.

Try:

```
tell application "Finder" to set view_type to list view
the_function(view_type)

on the_function(view_type)
    tell application "Finder"
        set current view of window 1 to view_type
    end tell
end the_function
```

you could also get tricky like:

```
the_function("lsvw" as constant) # lsvw, clvw, flvw, or icnv .

on the_function(view_type)
    tell application "Finder"
        set current view of window 1 to view_type
    end tell
end the_function
```

Comment: Great, thank you. The second way is what I need.  A follow-up question:  You changed `list view` to `lsvw`.  How did you know to do that?  Is there a reference you can refer me to that gives equivalent applescript representations:  list view = lsvw, column view = clvw, and so on?

Comment: I think that is internal to AppleScript and may not be well documented, or possibly subject to change. I got the values of the properties by (Sorry not formatting well):
`tell application "Finder"
 log list view as «class utf8»
 log column view as «class utf8»
 log icon view as «class utf8»
 log flow view as «class utf8»
end tell`

Comment: You can also use [Script Debugger](https://latenightsw.com), which will let you view the raw sources.